# Bubble Sort Alg & 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I have been at it for quite some time and I have not been able to solve the error ('int' object is not subscriptable) that is happening on my 4th line of code below.

I want the my counter variable to be compared to the previous index in the array, and if the element at the immediately previous index is larger, they are swapped.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
def bubble_sort(list_of_numbers):
    for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)): 


       for j in range(1,len(list_of_numbers)- i): 
           if list_of_numbers[j-1] > list_of_numbers[j]:

               temp = list_of_numbers[j-1]
               list_of_numbers[j-1] = list_of_numbers[j]
               list_of_numbers = temp 

   return list_of_numbers

unsorted_list = [20, 31, 5, 1, 591, 1351, 693]
print(unsorted_list)
print(bubble_sort(unsorted_list))enter code here
```

Comment: Problem is line `list_of_numbers = temp`.  You're assigning your list to an integer.

Comment: For future reference the simple pattern in Python for swapping two values is the single line: `list_of_numbers[j-1], list_of_numbers[j] = list_of_numbers[j], list_of_numbers[j-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
list_of_numbers = temp
```

you are assigning an integer to the variable `list_of_numbers` which causes the error.
So instead, use:

```
def bubble_sort(list_of_numbers):
    for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)): 


       for j in range(1,len(list_of_numbers)- i): 
           if list_of_numbers[j-1] > list_of_numbers[j]:

               temp = list_of_numbers[j-1]
               list_of_numbers[j-1] = list_of_numbers[j]
               list_of_numbers[j] = temp 

    return list_of_numbers

unsorted_list = [20, 31, 5, 1, 591, 1351, 693]
print(unsorted_list)
print(bubble_sort(unsorted_list))
```

or a better variable swap:

```
def bubble_sort(list_of_numbers):
    for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)): 


       for j in range(1,len(list_of_numbers)- i): 
           if list_of_numbers[j-1] > list_of_numbers[j]:

               list_of_numbers[j],list_of_numbers[j-1] = list_of_numbers[j-1],list_of_numbers[j]

    return list_of_numbers

unsorted_list = [20, 31, 5, 1, 591, 1351, 693]
print(unsorted_list)
print(bubble_sort(unsorted_list))
```